Recursive conditional interface in typescript
I want to create a recursive conditional interface in typescript.
It will look like this
Parent {
name: string,
code: not available if name is some specific string
subLayer: Parent but name and code will change depending on the name property above
}
I guess giving the code i wrote is better then trying to explain what i want to end up with.
This is what i tried and what i want to do so far
export enum AGLAYERTYPES {
  "AG Direk" = "MAESTRO_KCETAS:SBK_AGDIREK",
  "AG Hat" = "MAESTRO_KCETAS:SBK_AGHAT",
  "Aydınlatma Direği" = "MAESTRO_KCETAS:SBK_AYDDIREK",
  "Kofre" = "MAESTRO_KCETAS:SBK_KOFRE",
  "Pano" = "MAESTRO_KCETAS:SBK_PANO",
  "Rekortman" = "MAESTRO_KCETAS:SBK_REKORTMAN",
  "SDK" = "MAESTRO_KCETAS:SBK_SDK",
}
export enum OGLAYERTYPES {
  "Enh Direği" = "MAESTRO_KCETAS:SBK_ENHDIREK",
  "Kabloek" = "MAESTRO_KCETAS:SBK_KABLOEK",
  "OG Hat" = "MAESTRO_KCETAS:SBK_OGHAT",
  "OG Muş Direk" = "MAESTRO_KCETAS:SBK_OGMUSDIREK",
  "Trafo" = "MAESTRO_KCETAS:SBK_TRAFOBINATIP",
}
export enum BACKGROUNDLAYERTYPES {
  "Bina" = "MAESTRO_KCETAS:ADR_BINA",
  "Yol" = "MAESTRO_KCETAS:ADR_YOL",
  "Mahalle" = "MAESTRO_KCETAS:ADR_MAHALLE",
  "İlçeler" = "MAESTRO_KCETAS:ADR_ILCE",
  "İller" = "MAESTRO_KCETAS:ADR_IL",
}
type AgLayerGroup = "AG";
type OgLayerGroup = "OG";
type BackgroundLayerGroup = "Arkaplan";

This is what i want to end up with
const layers = [
  {
    name: "AG",
    visible: true,
    subLayers: [
      {
        name: "AG Direk",
        visible: true,
        code: AGLAYERTYPES["AG Direk"],
      },
      {
        name: "AG Hat",
        visible: true,
        code: AGLAYERTYPES["AG Hat"],
      },
      {
        name: "Aydınlatma Direği",
        visible: true,
        code: AGLAYERTYPES["Aydınlatma Direği"],
      },
      {
        name: "Kofre",
        visible: true,
        code: AGLAYERTYPES["Kofre"],
      },
      {
        name: "Pano",
        visible: true,
        code: AGLAYERTYPES["Pano"],
      },
      {
        name: "Rekortman",
        visible: true,
        code: AGLAYERTYPES["Rekortman"],
      },
      {
        name: "SDK",
        visible: true,
        code: AGLAYERTYPES["SDK"],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "OG",
    visible: true,
    subLayers: [
      {
        name: "Enh Direği",
        visible: true,
        code: OGLAYERTYPES["Enh Direği"],
      },
      {
        name: "Kabloek",
        visible: true,
        code: OGLAYERTYPES["Kabloek"],
      },
      {
        name: "OG Hat",
        visible: true,
        code: OGLAYERTYPES["OG Hat"],
      },
      {
        name: "OG Muş Direk",
        visible: true,
        code: OGLAYERTYPES["OG Muş Direk"],
      },
      {
        name: "Trafo",
        visible: true,
        code: OGLAYERTYPES["Trafo"],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Arkaplan",
    visible: true,
    subLayers: [
      {
        name: "Bina",
        visible: true,
        code: BACKGROUNDLAYERTYPES.Bina,
      },
      {
        name: "Yol",
        visible: true,
        code: BACKGROUNDLAYERTYPES.Yol,
      },
      {
        name: "Mahalle",
        visible: true,
        code: BACKGROUNDLAYERTYPES.Mahalle,
      },
      {
        name: "İlçeler",
        visible: true,
        code: BACKGROUNDLAYERTYPES.İlçeler,
      },
      {
        name: "İller",
        visible: true,
        code: BACKGROUNDLAYERTYPES.İller,
      },
    ],
  },
];

// pseudo interface
interface Layer {
  name:AgLayerGroup | OgLayerGroup | BackgroundLayerGroup | keyof AGLAYERTYPES | keyof OGLAYERTYPES | keyof BACKGROUNDLAYERTYPES;
  visible: true;
  // code: if name AgLayerGroup | OgLayerGroup | BackgroundLayerGroup ? never;
  // if name is AG then code: AGLAYERTYPES
  // if name is OG  then code: OGLAYERTYPES
  // if name is Arkaplan then code: BACKGROUNDLAYERTYPES
  // subLayers: Layer // recursive here.
}



Can you write out explicitly what you expect the output type to look like? If I write ILayers<OgLayerGroup>, what should that expand to, specifically? I don't understand your pseudocode or the stuff at the top of the question (which might need to be properly formatted).  Please [edit] to clarify.  It would also help if you made sure the code took up less vertical space, so it fits on a screen at once. (e.g., Unions where each line is a single union member should be reformatted to be just a single line)

(see prev comment) I suppose it's possible you're looking for something like this approach where you get a big union, but that can't be done directly with an interface. Does that work how you want? If so I could write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz i updated the question. You can see what i want to end up with at the end. Thank you for your effort

Pseudocode isn't very helpful to me. Is it subLayers or subLayer? Is it "ENH Direği" or "Enh Direği"? Every one of those I have to debug in my IDE is time that you should have spent fixing it in yours first. Could you triple check to make sure that everything is exactly correct and then I'll look at it?

(see prev comment). If I fix those, I get this which may or may not be what you want. If it's close enough, I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I still missing?

I edit my question again. Trying my best to be clear as possible. Sorry if cant make it

And again, is this version here, it's a playground link, click it close enough to what you want for me to post an answer? Or is it missing something? I'd really appreciate if you comment on that so I can know how to proceed.

I can add a subLayer to a subLayer object on your last comment. There needs to be a subLayer if the name property of the parent object is one of the layer groups like AgLayerGroup  or OgLayerGroup or BackgroundLayerGroup

So then is this better?  I truly wish you had actually written out the actual type you want to see instead of just an example of an array of that type.

Well i dont have a type for it. If i had i wouldnt ask a question. I tried to describe with text, pseudo code and the whole actual object i want to create. I dont know what more i can do. Sorry if its not clear. Your last answer is giving the expected result. But i am wondering whether it is possible to type it like at the end of my question or not

• "Well i dont have a type for it. If i had i wouldnt ask a question." You don't have a way to compute the type, but presumably you could describe it. You could have, for example, used a stripped down example (with just two enums, each containing two keys) and showed what the output type should look like. But the point is moot, I guess?  • So at this point I'd love to write up an answer but I'm not sure what you mean by your question. I defined it the way it should be defined. Your type is pseudocode with if in it. What specifically are you asking me?
